# How to write a program to trigger memory direct reclaim?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, memory, kernel-modules

First of all, I would like to kindly ask for your assistance in teaching me how to write a program that can trigger direct memory reclamation.

I wrote a program that utilizes mmap to allocate memory as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#define PAGE_SZ 4096
#define GB (1<<30)
int random_number(int min, int max) {
return min + rand() % (max - min + 1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
size_t size;
size = 5ul * GB;
printf("size %lu\n",size);

void *mem = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
if (mem == MAP_FAILED) {
perror("mmap");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

size_t num_pages = size / PAGE_SZ;

size_t i;
for (i = 0; i < num_pages; i++) {
*((char *)mem + i * PAGE_SZ) = '6';
}

srand(time(NULL));
while (1) {
size_t random_page = random_number(0, num_pages - 1);
char first_byte = *((char *)mem + random_page * PAGE_SZ);
}

return 0;
}
```

However, I noticed that only the available field decreased, while the free field did not show a significant decrease. This made it difficult to trigger direct memory reclamation.

So I am wondering how to make both the free and available fields decrease simultaneously?

I would greatly appreciate any advice or suggestions on how to write testing programs that can effectively trigger direct memory reclamation.

The reason why I want to conduct this test is as follows.

Recently, my server experienced several instances of hang, which lasted from several seconds to even ten minutes.

We have launched a program to monitor the call trace of processes in the 'D' state and the memory status.

Let me explain what I found during the hanging period first.

1. There were many processes in the 'D' state with a similar call trace: page_fault->...->filmap_fault()->__lock_page_or_retry()->io_schedule().
   No processes were hung in __alloc_page_slowpath.
2. The system triggered a direct memory reclaim, as observed through the logging that monitors the change of pgsteal_direct in /proc/vmstat every 2 seconds. The changes can range from tens to even ten million.
3. The available field and free field of 'free -h' were 15GB and 2GB respectively, before and after the direct reclamation occurred.

And here is some information about the server.
The server has 128GB of memory.
The value of /proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes is set to 2GB.
The swap file is disabled.

Based on this information, I believe:

1. Some processes triggered direct reclamation but did not hang.
2. The direct reclamation evicted some pages that belonged to other processes. (As far as I know, direct reclamation only evicts clean pages when it occurs.)
3. A group of processes triggered page faults, causing a high system load and resulting in them getting stuck.

To validate my hypothesis, I need to reproduce direct reclamation.

Comment: Setting vm.min_free_kbytes to 2GB is... very wrong. Doing so prohibits use outside of GFP_ATOMIC context and is likely to drastically starve your system of memory for no reason. Why would you do such a thing?

Comment: @ChrisDown Thanks for your reply. I am not yet familiar enough with memory system. Could you please teach me why setting vm.min_free_kbytes to 2GB is very wrong and likely to starve the system of memory? The total memory of my server is 128GB

Comment: your server memory is 128GB ,you just use a little (size = 5ul * GB;) so try arround it by for or Running many instances of this program